# Slim Twig not rendering out id's

Tags: php, slim, twig-extension

I have

```
{% if auth.renderFriendShip("{{auth.id}}", "{{user.id}}", 'isThereFriendship') == 0 %}
```

in my view file. It should be changing {{auth.id}} and {{user.id}}, but it isn't. When I run a "var_dump" on the {{user.id}} in my php model(where the function leads to)... it just outputs {{user.id}}.

Here is the relevant code in my view file...

```
{% if auth.renderFriendShip("{{auth.id}}", "{{user.id}}", 'isThereFriendship') == 0 %}
    <button class="friendBtn add" data-uid="{{user.id}}" data-type="addFriend">Friend</button>
    <button class="request_pending hidden" disabled>Request Pending</button>
{% else %}
    <button class="friendBtn unfriend" data-uid="{{user.id}}" data-type="unfriend">Unfriend</button>
    <button class="friendBtn add hidden" data-uid="{{user.id}}" data-type="addFriend">Add as friend</button>                        
    <button class="request_pending hidden" disabled>Request Pending</button>
{% endif %}
```

and my user model...

```
public function renderFriendShip($user_one, $user_two, $type) {
    if(!empty($user_one) || !empty($user_two) || !empty($type)) {
        switch($type) {
            case 'isThereRequestPending':
                $matchThese = ['user_one' => "$user_one", 'user_two' => "$user_two", 'friendship_official' => '0'];
                $orMatchThese = ['user_one' => "$user_two", 'user_two' => "$user_one", 'friendship_official' => '0'];

                $query = $this->friendsList()
                    ->where($matchThese)
                    ->orWhere($orMatchThese)
                    ->get()
                    ->count();

                return $query;
                break;
            case 'isThereFriendship':
                $q = $this->friendsList()
                    ->where(function($query) use ($user_one, $user_two) {
                        return $query->where(['user_one' => $user_one, 'user_two' => $user_two, 'friendship_official' => '1']);
                    })
                    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($user_one, $user_two) {
                        return $query->where(['user_one' => $user_two, 'user_two' => $user_one, 'friendship_official' => '1']);
                    })
                    ->get()
                    ->count();

                break;
        }
        return var_dump($user_two);
    } else {
        return "Failed";
    }
}
```

Thank you for any possible advice you can give me. I have been searching for hours now and I haven't found a solution.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to return $q in the case of "isThereFriendship"

Comment: @Jacques I added that and moved my var dump (where the return query is supposed to be... its now "return var_dump($q);"). Im still getting int(0) for my return when there indeed is the correct information in both the db and my code. The "{{auth.id}}" and "{{user.id}}" probably still arent changing

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but if var dump is not returning anything, then are you sure you're actually running the query, I don't see the query actually being used, just set, in your code. If you're not running the query, it's not going to pull from the database.

Comment: @Jacques no it is running because when I sub in "1" and "2" on the views page it actually works. Slim just isn't changing the "{{auth.id}}" and "{{user.id}}"

Comment: If the data is there, as you say, then something has to be different from 1 to 2. Otherwise it would work. The 30 lines of PHP you posted does't really give much to go on. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is simple: in your twig file you're referencing to `auth.id` and `user.id` using curly braces. Try to use:

```
{% if auth.renderFriendShip(auth.id, user.id, 'isThereFriendship') == 0 %}
```

From [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables):

> It's important to know that the curly braces are not part of the
>   variable but the print statement. When accessing variables inside
>   tags, don't put the braces around them.

Comment: I did actually figure this out myself after some time... thank you though for actually posting this! Marked as answer